# compojure route with multiple parameters

Tags: clojure, compojure, clout

Is it possible to define a compojure route that contains multiple parameters?

i.e:

```
(def my-routes
  (routes 
    (GET "/something/:param1/:param2" [] my-handler)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
(GET "/something/:param1/:param2" [param1 param2]
    (str {:first param1 :second param2}))
```